# Prevent duplicate entries parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as my backend and while there seems to be a method, `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, to prevent duplicate entries. It doesn't appear to exist on Android. I'd like to upload only unique entries but can't figure out a way to do so.

The only thing I can think of is to query then insert if the entry doesn't exist, but that's doing twice as many network calls and I feel like it needs to.

Thanks

Comment: Faced the same problem. Ended up writing a query to find the existing objects and then save only the non-existing ones.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 3):

As I had mentioned in the comment earlier, I had faced the same problem. Ended up writing a query to find the existing objects and then save only the non-existing ones. Like below.

//Say you have a list of ParseObjects..this list contains the existing as well as the new objects.

```
List<ParseObject> allObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
allObjects.add(object); //this contains the entire list of objects.
```

You want to find out the existing ones by using the field say ids.

```
//First, form a query
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Class");
query.whereContainedIn("ids", allIds); //allIds is the list of ids

List<ParseObject> Objects = query.find();  //get the list of the parseobjects..findInBackground(Callback) whichever is suitable

for (int i = 0; i < Objects.size(); i++)
      existingIds.add(Objects.get(i).getString("ids"));

List<String> idsNotPresent = new ArrayList<String>(allIds);
idsNotPresent.removeAll(existingIds);

//Use a list of Array objects to store the non-existing objects
List<ParseObject> newObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < selectedFriends.size(); i++) {
     if (idsNotPresent.contains(allObjects.get(i).getString(
                        "ids"))) {
     newObjects.add(allObjects.get(i)); //new Objects will contain the list of only the ParseObjects which are new and are not existing.
    }
}

//Then use saveAllInBackground to store this objects

ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(newObjects, new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //do something
        }
    });
```

I had also tried using `beforeSave` method on `ParseCloud`. As you may know, before saving the objects this method is called on the `ParseCloud` and is ideal to make any validation required. But, it didn't quite run well. Let me know if you need something from the `ParseCloud` code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BackpackOnHead did this help? Did you find a better way to do it? Do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please answer this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801533/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-distinct-contacts-in-android ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can get the same functionality as `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` in Android like this:

```
myObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
           myObjectSavedSuccessfully();
        } else {
           myObjectSaveDidNotSucceed();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to avoid saving duplicate entries.

Comment: You could only save duplicate entries if you call save on an object more than once. Please provide some context in your question so that we can understand why you are forced to perform multiple save calls on the same object.